# Retrieve cookie info from json format

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have cookie info stored in JSON format as follows:

```
var preferredAnimal = {
    "dog" : "true",
    "cat" : "false",
    "bird" : "true"
};
```

How would i just extract the info for one item? For example, i just want to check cookie, and do something if bird returns true.

Checking the cookie in devtools, the Name is preferredAnimal, and the value is {"dog":true,"cat":false,"bird":true}, so trying to identify the value gives me everything.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
if(preferredAnimal.bird == 'true')
{
   //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you used `JSON.stringify` to stringify your cookie, you can get it in its orignal form by using this function:

```
function getCookieAsJSON(name) {
  const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
  const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
  if (parts.length === 2) 
     return JSON.parse(
          parts.pop()
         .split(';')
         .shift()
     );
}
```

Usage:

```js
const cookie = getCookieAsJSONI('preferredAnimal') // preferredAnimal is the name of your cookie
console.log(cookie) // Returned cookie is an object just as your orignal object if you used JSON.stringify
```

Output:

```
 {
   dog: "true",
   cat: "false",
   bird:"true"
 }
```

Note, your values will be strings but you can cast them to the proper types easily.